# Is it safe to delete file if error occurs during file saving from InputStream?

Tags: java

For example I want to save large file (3G+) from web. Code sample:

```
try {
    Files.copy(inputstream, destFilePath);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Files.deleteIfExists(destFilePath);
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputstream);  
}
```

According to JavaDoc for `deleteIfExists`:

> On some operating systems it may not be possible to remove a file when
>        * it is open and in use by this Java virtual machine or other programs.

Is it safe to delete file in a such way? `Files.copy` release output stream even error occurs, does it guarantee that JVM released lock on the file?

Comment: you could call file.close() before deleting it.

Comment: @ivange94, I'm not sure that I can find this method `File::close`.

Comment: Yes sorry. That method is actually present but in the FileInputStream. Not File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file should not be in use in your case. Take into consideration that Files.copy does not ask you for an OutputStream or File, just for a path. It would be weird that it could leave a file descriptor open upon exit, no matter if exception or not; the File api would be broken in that case IMO. In any case, File javadoc would inform you of that possibility.

In any case, if you want to minimise possibilities of file not being deleted, you can add also a file.deleteOnExit(); then when jvm terminates, it will do another try to delete file (unless jvm terminates abnormally).

Comment: It takes Path and creates OutputStream inside `copy` method.

Comment: i know, what i mean is that the outputstream is not an input param, but instead is created by the Files.copy method itself. So it's responsability of that method to release properly everything. Otherwise it would be a flaw; at least, if not explicitly stated on javadoc (if you are curious, you can look into Files source code and you will see it is actually closing the outputstream it creates).

Comment: You are right about releasing output stream. I think that I have some kind of paranoia =).